# C# MongoDB Driver filter subdocument list based on incoming array

Tags: c#, filtering, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following C# model structure:

```
public class Box
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("relatedJobs")]
    public List<BoxJobs> RelatedJobs { get; init; } = default!;

    //more properties

    public class BoxJobs
    {
        [BsonElement("partnerId")]
        public string PartnerId { get; init; } = null!;
        
        //more properties
    }
}
```

There is a need to filter all the boxes based in an incoming `partnerIds` array. In other words I want to retrieve every single `box` that has at least one `relatedJob` with its `partnerId` present in the incoming array.

I've tried the following:

```
var builder = Builders<Box>.Filter;
var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Box>().Empty;
filter &= !partnerIds.Any()
        ? new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Box>().Empty
        : builder.AnyIn(box => box.RelatedJobs.Select(relatedJob => relatedJob.PartnerId), partnerIds);
var cursor = Collection.Find(filter);
```

This results in the following error:

```
Unable to determine the serialization information for box => box.RelatedJobs.Select(relatedJob => relatedJob.PartnerId).
```

I have also tried creating a `PartnerIds` property in `Box` which returns the same `Select` result, and use it in the `AnyIn` function but it didn't help either.

How can I do this filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you need to check that RelatedJobs contains a job pith PartnerId from `partnerIds` list. `Fields.ElemMatch` method [returns the first matching element](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.8/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_Builders_Fields_ElemMatch.htm) in the array specified by name.

```
var builder = Builders<Box>.Filter;
var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Box>().Empty;
filter &= !partnerIds.Any()
        ? new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Box>().Empty
        : builder.ElemMatch(x => x.RelatedJobs, j => partnerIds.Contains(j.PartnerId));
var cursor = Collection.Find(filter);
```